# How can I eliminate a bad smell coming from under my dishwasher?

Tags: smell

Whirlpool Dishwasher smells bad when hot water starts. Not inside the dishwasher, outside/underneath. I detect no water leaks, it seems like it is coming from the pump underneath. The smell comes out from cracks under the dishwasher when it starts running, then lingers for the next 8 hours.

Comment: Define "stinks" : burning plastic/rubber, sewer waste, dead animal, etc.

Comment: There are several answered questions on DIY.SE regarding bad smells from dishwashers. If you haven't tried some of those options, they may help identify the smell.

Comment: smells like a dead animal/rotten food in water, took out dishwasher, nothing underneath, no water, no dead mouse, just smell right around the pump. Inside smells fine, cleaned out filter inside, Little bit of water in catch where filter is but it does not smell. Tried vinegar, helped a little. But everytime I run the dishwasher it starts smelling when hot water enters, then when it hits the dry cycle, the stink is so bad even the cat goes to another room. My gut feeling just tells me to go buy a new dishwasher.